# Performance difference between MongoServer.Create() and mongoClient.GetServer() in MongoDb

Tags: c#, performance, mongodb

Consider this code:

```
     MongoServer mongo = MongoServer.Create();
        mongo.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        Console.WriteLine();

        MongoDatabase db = mongo.GetDatabase("tutorial");
        Stopwatch stopwatch=new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        using (mongo.RequestStart(db))
        {
            MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("books");

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                var nested = new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"name", "John Doe"},

                };
                collection.Insert(nested);
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

In the first line i use MongoServer.Create() which is obsolete.But when running above code output time is `3056`(approximately 3 seconds).

So I use this code that is recommended by MongoDb documentation.

```
 MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
            var server = mongo.GetServer();

            MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("tutorial");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            using (server.RequestStart(db))
            {
                MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("books");

                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                {
                    var nested = new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"name", "John Doe"},

                    };
                    collection.Insert(nested);
                }
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.ReadLine();
```

When run above code the output time is `14225`(approximately 10 to 14 second on my PC).
Why i get this performance time as a result of refactored code on new version of mongoDb.What i am missing along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that you're seeing the difference between the write concern being enabled by default in the newer drivers when using the recommended connection pattern (as you're doing in the second example).

The change was made in November 2012:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/

Prior to this change, writes were not being acknowledged by default, so you would see "faster" writes.

There's a little more detail about the C# changes [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Release%20Notes/Release%20Notes%20v1.7.md).

If you'd like to experiment with the new style connection, you could disable the WriteConcern for the database connection in your test:

```
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("tutorial", WriteConcern.Unacknowledged);
```

and then rerun your tests to compare performance.

Comment: This exactly what i was looking for.with WriteConcern.Unacknowledged set i got same performance.thank you.